# Error from process builder triggering email action on case

Tags: process-builder, case, email-alert

I am getting the error

> Error Occurred: Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients

from process builder. Based on Salesforce documentation, this happens if the email field is null. However, this email action that the process builder is triggering is set up on the case object to send to 'Related Contact or Lead Owner'. There isn't a contact owner but there's always a lead owner so I'm not sure how this error is occurring.

Comment: Does your Contact have an email?
or Does your Lead Owner have an email?

Comment: The contact does not but the lead owner does. Given that it's **OR** I thought it would just ignore the contact and send to the lead owner.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that
if there is no contact on the case then only it will go to the lead, otherwise, it will look for the Contact's email and send the email.

Comment: There is no contact on the case, sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: Are you sure Lead Owner is Active user and has a valid email?

Comment: Case doesn't have a lookup to a Lead. Do you have any custom lookup field?

Comment: Yes there's a custom loookup field